# Oceans as global background won't reproject properly

Tags: r, sf, ggplot2, ggplot

I'm trying to get an line for the edge of the globe (or a polygon for the oceans as an equivalent) with ggplot and sf. My code works for a basic Mollweide projection ...

```
library(tmap)
library(sf)
library(s2)
sf_use_s2(TRUE) 
data("World") ## get built-in data from the tmap package
world.sf <- World

lat <- c(seq(from=-90,to=90,by=0.25)) ## creates a sequence -90 to 90 by 0.25
lon <- c(rep(180,length(lat)),rep(-180,length(lat))) # creates a sequence of 180 and -180 longitudes
oceans.df <- data.frame("lon"=lon, "lat"=c(lat,lat)) ## combines the point in a data frame
oceans.sf <- st_as_sf(oceans.df,coords = c("lon","lat"), crs=4326) %>% 
  st_union() %>% # combines the points into a MULTIPOINT
  st_convex_hull() # gets the outline of the points

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data=oceans.sf, fill="blue") ## fine for Mercator


oceans_moll.sf <- st_as_sf(oceans.df,coords = c("lon","lat"), crs=4326) %>% 
  st_transform(crs="+proj=moll") %>% ## 
  st_union() %>% # combines the points into a MULTIPOINT
  st_convex_hull() # gets the outline of the points

world_moll.sf <- st_transform(world.sf, crs="+proj=moll")
ggplot() + ## This looks great
  geom_sf(data=oceans_moll.sf, fill="blue") + geom_sf(data=world_moll.sf, fill="white")
```

But it fails for a Mollweide centered on the Pacific

```
oceans_moll_pacific.sf <- st_as_sf(oceans.df,coords = c("lon","lat"), crs=4326) %>% 
  st_transform(crs="+proj=moll +lon_0=-150 +x_0=0 +y_0=0") %>% ## 
  st_union() %>% # combines the points into a MULTIPOINT
  st_convex_hull() # gets the outline of the points

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data=oceans_moll_pacific.sf, fill="blue")
```

Not quite sure what's going wrong. I've tried to define the globe using the code below from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72945320/sfst-transform-returns-empty-geometry/72954190#72954190 but that doesn't work with reprojections either.

```
ocean <- st_point(x = c(0,0)) %>%
  st_buffer(dist = 6371000) %>%
  st_sfc(crs = "+proj=ortho +lat_0=20 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371000 +b=6371000 +units=m +no_defs")
```

Not sure what's going wrong here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that your outline in `oceans.df` is centred on 0 longitude and so tied to +/-180 degrees. When transformed it becomes a line that is still at the 180 longitude line:

```
plot(st_transform(world.sf$geom,crs="+proj=moll +lon_0=-150 +x_0=0 +y_0=0"))
plot(oceans_moll_pacific.sf,add=TRUE, border="red",lwd=2)
```

[image]

If you want to create the outline of a Mollweide projection centred on -150 then that has to come from coordinates at -150+180 and -150-180. Both these numbers are 30 degrees longitude which makes things a bit tricky since they get projected to the same side of the transformed sphere. Adjusting them by a tiny amount fixes this, in this case 0.01 degrees.

First compute the sequence round the Mollweide boundary centred on -150:

```r
eps = 0.01
lat <- c(seq(from=-90,to=90,by=0.25))
lon <- c(rep(30-eps,length(lat)),rep(30+eps,length(lat)))
```

Next I'll create that as an `sf` polygon object by casting from a line made from the points (seems more direct than the union and convex polygon approach). Note how I reverse the latitude sequence for one side to make a continuous polygon.

```r
oceans = st_transform(
          st_sfc(
            st_cast(
              st_linestring(
                cbind(lon, c(lat, rev(lat))
              )
            ),"POLYGON"),
            crs=4326),
         crs="+proj=moll +lon_0=-150 +x_0=0 +y_0=0")
```

Now if I plot this over the transformed world you'll see it looks right. Of course the transformed world is a mess because all the polygons being split at 30 degrees...

```r
plot(st_transform(world.sf$geom,crs="+proj=moll +lon_0=-150 +x_0=0 +y_0=0"))
plot(oceans,add=TRUE,border="red")
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, thanks. The vector recycling in cbind(lon, c(lat, rev(lat)) is a nice touch! Since sf and ggplot seem to like tidyverse piping, I'm going to tweak this and post it with attribution to Stackoverflow

Comment: In practice I'd avoid the pipes and the nested functions like I did above and do it in stages instead - assign each stage to a new object so that you can check its what you expect. Wrapped into a function so that the intermediate objects don't clutter your space. May rewrite later for you parameterised by the offset longitude...

Comment: Actually I've just realised that this polygon works for any Mollweide `+lon_0` value as long as the other parameters are the same, because any projected Mollweide will have 0,0 in the middle and the same projected values round the edge. The projection will be wrong which probably messes up `geom_sf` though...

Comment: I posted a roughly parameterized version to Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77274877/show-globes-edge-or-ocean-background-using-sf-and-ggplot  I agree that stages are better than piping for developing code ... I use piping once the code works! Thanks again